# Java SOAP client optimisations and async client

Tags: jaxb, protocol-buffers, thrift, soap-client, vert.x

Need to consume a third party web service exposed over SOAP. But the response is having too deep object graphs and the response time is very high: 40-60 sec. 
JAXB marshalling and unmarshalling also add significant latency on top of it. Is there a way to reduce the latency using protobuf/thrift. Also some recent application modules are migrated to Vertx. While CXF has `asychHttpClient` built in, is there any equivalent module in Vertx. What is the advantage of using it over CXF client?

Comment: If the service exposed to you is SOAP ... well, for starters you will have to convince the other side to rewrite their entire API layer.

Comment: Are the 40-60 second the time between the request and the response to your external SOAP WS or it is also spent inside your own layer/service to transform (marshal/unmarshal) the received objects?

Comment: @ruffp Basically the spring soap client, it return result object after marshal/unmarshal is done, so yes it include marshal/unmarshal time

Comment: When you send the request, do you use the async method of CXF client?

Comment: yes. The request response time is kind of same in sync/async client. The advantage I had is more concurrent requests I can make. Its like `Future<Response> responseFuture = webclient.async().get()`

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing 2 separate issues here.

1) The third party service takes 40-60 seconds to respond.

Most like there is no way for you to speed up the response so you have to deal with it as it is, and the choice you use just depends on your application.  Vert.x may help in this regard because it is asynchronous by design.

2) The object graph of the response is large and JAXB deserialization has serious overhead.

Most likely Thrift or Protocol Buffers won't help you too much because they are completely different technologies than SOAP/XML.  Probably the issue you are having is the fact that JAXB reads the entire message into memory and then creates a complete object graph for it, regardless of the amount of data you actually need.  If you don't actually need all of the data, you should investigate using something like the Streaming API for XML (StAX) that is part of the Java platform.  It allows you to parse an XML message without creating an object model for data that you do not need.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any preference of STAX over XSLT, performance wise.XSLT can also transform soap response to json response (string).

Comment: It just depends on your use case.  Also I'm not sure how transforming the response to JSON fits into the picture.  If you're dealing with a very large SOAP response and you only need a small part of the data, I personally would consider using StAX since it gives you the most control over how the parsing is done.  If you need to convert to JSON you might want to combine using StAX with something like this: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi